# How do I add `const` values at compile time and use them as generic argument in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust, compile-time

I would like to write a function which takes two input arguments which have `const` generic arguments `A` and `B` in their types and which returns a type that has the sum `A+B` as a `const` generic argument. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
pub struct X<const A: usize>();

pub fn f<const A: usize, const B: usize>(_: X<A>, _: X<B>) -> X<A + B> {
    X()
}
```

Unfortunately, the compiler yells at me with the following error message:

```
error[E0404]: expected trait, found const parameter `A` 
--> <source>:3:65  
  | 
3 | pub fn f<const A: usize, const B: usize>(_: X<A>, _: X<B>) -> X<A + B> {  
  |                                                                 ^ not a trait

error[E0404]: expected trait, found const parameter `B` 
--> <source>:3:69
  |
3 | pub fn f<const A: usize, const B: usize>(_: X<A>, _: X<B>) -> X<A + B> {
  |                                                                     ^ not a trait

error[E0747]: type provided when a constant was expected 
--> <source>:3:65
  |
3 | pub fn f<const A: usize, const B: usize>(_: X<A>, _: X<B>) -> X<A + B> {
  |                                                                 ^^^^^

error: aborting due to 3 previous errors
```

I find the error messages quite confusing. If I put braces around `A + B`, then the error message changes to this:

```
error: generic parameters may not be used in const operations 
--> <source>:3:66
  |
3 | pub fn f<const A: usize, const B: usize>(_: X<A>, _: X<B>) -> X<{A + B}> {
  |                                                                  ^ cannot perform const operation using `A`
  |  = help: const parameters may only be used as standalone arguments, i.e. `A`

error: generic parameters may not be used in const operations 
--> <source>:3:70
  |
3 | pub fn f<const A: usize, const B: usize>(_: X<A>, _: X<B>) -> X<{A + B}> {
  |                                                                      ^ cannot perform const operation using `B`
  |  = help: const parameters may only be used as standalone arguments, i.e. `B`
```

which seems a bit better, but I don't understand why adding `A` and `B` is prohibited here.

So my two questions are:

- Why is it prohibited to add `A` and `B` here?
- Is there any way to work around this limitation?

I checked on https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/generics.html#const-generics and there I can find the restriction that

> const parameters may only appear as a standalone argument inside of a type or array repeat expression.

But there's no hint on why there is that restriction or how to work around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a limitation of rustc. Const generics, at least on stable, haven't passed the minimum viable product phase of development. Currently, that means const generics can only take the values of plain constants, whether they come from generic parameters, literals, or regular const items. There are two different workarounds, depending on your needs.

Option 1: use the `generic_const_exprs` feature:

```rust
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]

pub struct X<const A: usize>();

pub fn f<const A: usize, const B: usize>(_: X<A>, _: X<B>) -> X<{A + B}> {
    X()
}
```

Obviously, it only works on nightly. Also, it's an incomplete feature, and while I don't think there are any soundness issues, there are more than a few rough edges, at least as of nightly version 1.67.

Option 2: use a third generic parameter:

```rust
pub struct X<const A: usize>();

pub fn f<const A: usize, const B: usize, const C: usize>(_: X<A>, _: X<B>) -> X<C> {
    assert_eq!(A + B, C);
    X()
}
```

This works on stable, and is what I recommend you do. The downside is that the invariant checking happens at runtime, even though the check can be evaluated at compile time. It's a little less ergonomic than the nightly solution, but much more likely to behave, and lets you check arbitrarily complicated invariants, even those only fully known at runtime.